# Checking Client Action on WFFM does not attach file to email

Tags: wffm

We have 2 save actions concerning sending emails, one is Send Email Message and the other is Send Email Message with Attachment. The difference is that the Client Action is checked on the former while it is not on the latter.

However, when using a not-required File Upload field on a form with Send Email Message with Attachment save action, the form is sending duplicate emails if the form does not contain a file attached.

If I checked the Client Action the email is sent only once but the email is not attached.

Have you encountered this scenario and what are the workarounds you took to resolve this?

PS: `<IsIncludeAttachments>true</IsIncludeAttachments>` is already configured